# perform calculations on API data in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, date-arithmetic

permission to ask, I'm a little confused about the problem I'm having, I want to do addition, division, times and other calculations using the API data below, but I'm confused about how I do data calculations in the API,
is there anyone here who wants to give an example of calculation of API data?
because if using local data in variables I can use but what if the data comes from API.
Thank You.

[image]

this is an example when i do a local computation on a variable
[image]

and what if i do calculations if using data from API

```
Future<NilaiMahasiswa> getNilaiMahasiswa(int semester) async {
    String url = Constant.baseURL;
    String token = await UtilSharedPreferences.getToken();
    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse(
        '$url/auth/mhs_siakad/transkrip_nilai?semester=$semester',
      ),
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
      },
    );

    print(response.statusCode);
    print(response.body);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return NilaiMahasiswa.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    } else {
      throw Exception();
    }
  }
```

Comment: You need to calculate your data on server or on client (phone, tablet, etc.)?

Comment: yes, because the back end is not provided so I have to calculate it myself on the front end to be displayed to the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your example is that those digits you seeing are actually of  `String` type, not a `num` type (`int` or `double`), so taking this example:

```
String stringExample = "100";
String stringExample2 = "200";
print(stringExample  + stringExample2); // 100200
```

because they are both `String`, it will just concatenate them.

```
int intExample = 100;
int intExample2 = 200;
print(intExample2 + intExample); // 300
```

will calculate the sum of them because they are actual numbers.

now take an example like your code:

```
final mapExample = {
"nilay_akhir_uas": "90",
"nilay_akhir": "90.33",
}
```

we can get the value in this `Map` with its key like this:

```
print(mapExample["nilay_akhir_uas"]); // "90"
```

and trying to do a math calculation over them:

```
  print(mapExample["nilay_akhir_uas"]! + mapExample["nilay_akhir"]!); // 9090.33
```

Because as we said the `String` elements get concatenated even if you see that they contain numbers, it is still a `String`

**So how can we achieve a math calculation over `String` which contains a number like this?**

we need to parse them, and Dart offers a useful method for this, such as `int.parse()`, `int.tryParse()`..., so we can do this:

```
int nilay_akhir_uas = int.parse(mapExample["nilay_akhir_uas"]!); // 90 as int
double nilay_akhir = double.parse(mapExample["nilay_akhir"]!); // 93.33 as double

print(nilay_akhir_uas + nilay_akhir); // 180.33
```

The `int.parse()` and `double.parse()` will parse a `String` to a number of its possible, otherwise, it will throw an exception.

if you want to avoid the exception and get a `null` when it can't parse the `String`, then consider using `int.tryParse()` and `double.tryParse()`:

**int** :

```
int.parse("10"); // return 10
int.tryParse("10"); // return 10
int.parse("test"); // throws exception
int.tryParse("test"); // return null
```

**double** :

```
double.parse("99.99"); // return 99.99
double.tryParse("99.99"); // return 99.99
double.parse("test"); // throws exception
double.tryParse("test"); // return null
```

Comment: I've updated my question, where should I put it?